ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity found - Azure Synapse PySpark
We are trying to generate token for custom rest api endpoint. We are using Azure Synapse Notebook in PySpark.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential,ManagedIdentityCredential
import requests

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id='xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx')

This code execute successfully without error. I know alternatively we can use ClientSecret authentication but because of complaince reason we have to use ManagedIdentityCredential only.
But using credential object if we try to get_token it throws error
token = credential.get_token("api://xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/.default")


ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential
authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- CredentialUnavailableError                Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In [9], line 1
----> 1 token = credential.get_token("api://xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/.default")
File
~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/decorators.py:27,
in log_get_token..decorator..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
24 @functools.wraps(fn)
25 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
26     try:
---> 27         token = fn(*args, **kwargs)
28         _LOGGER.info("%s succeeded", qualified_name)
29         return token
File
~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/managed_identity.py:93, in ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token(self, *scopes, **kwargs)
91 if not self._credential:
92     raise CredentialUnavailableError(message="No managed identity endpoint found.")
---> 93 return self._credential.get_token(*scopes, **kwargs)
File
~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/managed_identity.py:190,
in ImdsCredential.get_token(self, *scopes, **kwargs)
188 if not self._endpoint_available:
189     message = "ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found."
--> 190     raise CredentialUnavailableError(message=message)
192 if len(scopes) != 1:
193     raise ValueError("This credential requires exactly one scope per token request.")
CredentialUnavailableError: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication
unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.


You need to run the start session on pool enabling managed identity.
Follow below steps to enable.
Click on configure session

then enable Run as managed identity and apply it.

EDIT
According to this documentation

Synapse notebooks and Spark job definitions only support the use of system-assigned managed identity through linked services and the mssparkutils APIs.

also

User-assigned Managed Identity is not currently supported in Synapse notebooks and Spark job definitions.

So, whatever the token you need can be retrieved using mssparkutils.credentials.getToken("Storage")

Sorry I didn't mention this in original question but I have already enabled this.

What is the spark version you are using?  Stop current session try it in new session or create new pool and run it.

@arpandesai i have updated the solution kindly check it.

Has anyone tried this for cosmosdb linked service and able to get it working??
